# Observable emit values not getting delayed

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to create an observable which will emit delayed values. However the values are getting instataneously. I have created a stackblitz at https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-cwixas. The code is given below:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
const source = of(...arr);
const source2 = source.pipe(delay(2000));
const subscribe = source2.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: do want delay each value or just the array?

Comment: each array value should be emitted at the interval of 2 seconds. Emit 1, wait 2 seconds, emit 2, wait 2 seconds and so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `delay()` operator just adds delay to each `next` value but it doesn't care whether the previous delay elapsed.

So what happens here is that `of()` immediately emits 5 values where all 5 are scheduled to be re-emitted by `delay` at the same time after 2s.

You'll have to use for example `concatMap` that will project each value into an Observable and wait until that completes. Only then continue with another value:

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
const source = of(...arr).pipe(
  concatMap(value => of(value).pipe(
    delay(2000),
  )),
);

source.subscribe(...);
```

Your update demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-cknhbr?file=index.ts